# duplicating the whole svg element using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am creating a `rectangle` using `d3.js`, inside that rectangle i am creating 10 smaller rectangles`.

i want to replicate whole thing into another svg element on mouse click.

`jsfiddle` link of the code : http://jsfiddle.net/nikunj2512/XK585/

Here is the code:

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", 200)
.attr("height", 200);

//Draw the Rectangle
var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect")
.attr("x", 10)
.attr("y", 10)
.attr("fill", "red")
.attr("width", 200)
.attr("height", 200);

var bigRectContainer = d3.select('#bigRectContainer').append('svg')
    .attr('width', 200)
    .attr('height', 200);
var dim = 20;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

    x = 10 + (i-1)*dim;
    //alert(x);
y = 10;

    svgContainer.append("rect")
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .style("fill", "black");
 }

 var bigRectContainer = svgContainer.append("g");
 svgContainer.selectAll("rect").on("click", function () {
 var littleRect = d3.select(this);
console.log(littleRect)

var bigRect = bigRectContainer.selectAll("rect")
                       .data(littleRect)
                       .enter()
                       .append("rect");

 });
```

Please tell me where i made the mistake...

Comment: You're doing about 5 different things in your code. I suggest that you go back to the start and try to first append one rectangle, then additional ones.

Comment: Lars :  i didn't get what are You trying to say... Please explain more clearly...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what you're trying to do with the code you've posted, but I thought that duplicating an entire SVG node was interesting. It turns out it's quite easy to do with `selection#html` - this doesn't work on the SVG node, but it *does* work on its container, so it's easy to clone the whole node:

```
function addAnother() {
    var content = d3.select(this.parentNode).html();
    var div = d3.select('body').append('div')
        .html(content);
    div.selectAll('svg').on('click', addAnother);
}

svg.on('click', addAnother);
```

See [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L6u9x/). Note that this only works if the SVG node is the only child of its parent - otherwise, you might need to wrap it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

D3 doesn't provide cloning functionality, probably because of the native [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method that already exists on DOM elements, including SVG nodes.

This method includes a boolean parameter to deep copy (i.e. copy all descendants) instead of just cloning the node it is called on. You would probably want to do something like `bigRectContainer.node().cloneNode(true)` to copy the entire DOM branch of rectangles.

Comment: d3.select(bigRectContainer).node().cloneNode(true)   this worked for me.